# Jolt Transformation in nifi with Nested Arrays

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to create a jolt transformation in NIFI , I have a JSON message with *header*, *detail* and *line details* as an array with line detail object.

Can we Transform Header/Detail JSON into Detail JSON
One separate JSON for each Detail with 2 New Tags having flattened array of Detail Attribute values of "TRADETYP" and "TRANSPORT_CODE"

"TRADETYPALLLINES": [ "GR","EXP","SE"]
"TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": [ "BARGE","ES","AR"]

Here is the sample JSON :

```json
{
  "TRADE_HEADER": {
    "TRADEDETAIL": {
      "SEGMENT": "1",
      "TRADE_NUM": "NA-152",
      "PACKAGE_GUID": "ASDER3785$%SDF",
      "TRADEDETAILLINE": [
        {
          "DOC_QTY": "19956.930",
          "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
          "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
          "XMDOCNR": "5025087976",
          "DOCITM": "0000012001",
          "COMMODITY": "RB",
          "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
          "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
          "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
          "MARKET": "CME",
          "TRADETYP": "GR",
          "MAX_DOC_QTY": "19956.930",
          "TRANSPORT_CODE": "BARGE",
          "DOCNR": "4700253115"
        },
        {
          "DOC_QTY": "12256.230",
          "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
          "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
          "XMDOCNR": "5025092776",
          "DOCITM": "0000014021",
          "COMMODITY": "RB",
          "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
          "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
          "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
          "MARKET": "CME",
          "TRADETYP": "EXP",
          "MAX_DOC_QTY": "12256.230",
          "TRANSPORT_CODE": "ES",
          "DOCNR": "4700234521"
        },
        {
          "DOC_QTY": "14256.210",
          "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
          "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
          "XMDOCNR": "5025023562",
          "DOCITM": "0000012041",
          "COMMODITY": "RB",
          "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
          "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
          "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
          "MARKET": "CME",
          "TRADETYP": "SE",
          "MAX_DOC_QTY": "14256.230",
          "TRANSPORT_CODE": "AR",
          "DOCNR": "4700278453"
        }
      ],
      "PACKAGE_SEQ_NBR": "1",
      "PACKAGE_SEQ_MAX_NBR": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Desired JSON :**

```json
[
  {
    "TRADERECORD": {
      "TRADE_NUM": "NA-152",
      "PACKAGE_GUID": "ASDER3785$%SDF",
      "DOC_QTY": "19956.930",
      "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
      "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
      "XMDOCNR": "5025087976",
      "DOCITM": "0000012001",
      "COMMODITY": "RB",
      "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
      "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
      "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
      "MARKET": "CME",
      "TRADETYP": "GR",
      "MAX_DOC_QTY": "19956.930",
      "TRANSPORT_CODE": "BARGE",
      "DOCNR": "4700253115",
      "TRADETYPALLLINES": [
        "GR",
        "EXP",
        "SE"
      ],
      "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": [
        "BARGE",
        "ES",
        "AR"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "TRADERECORD": {
      "TRADE_NUM": "NA-152",
      "PACKAGE_GUID": "ASDER3785$%SDF",
      "DOC_QTY": "12256.230",
      "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
      "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
      "XMDOCNR": "5025092776",
      "DOCITM": "0000014021",
      "COMMODITY": "RB",
      "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
      "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
      "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
      "MARKET": "CME",
      "TRADETYP": "EXP",
      "MAX_DOC_QTY": "12256.230",
      "TRANSPORT_CODE": "ES",
      "DOCNR": "4700234521",
      "TRADETYPALLLINES": [
        "GR",
        "EXP",
        "SE"
      ],
      "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": [
        "BARGE",
        "ES",
        "AR"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "TRADERECORD": {
      "TRADE_NUM": "NA-152",
      "PACKAGE_GUID": "ASDER3785$%SDF",
      "DOC_QTY": "14256.210",
      "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY": "0.000",
      "REM_MAX_QTY_TE": "0.000",
      "XMDOCNR": "5025023562",
      "DOCITM": "0000012041",
      "COMMODITY": "RB",
      "TRADING_COMPANY": "3862",
      "PERIODICITY": "PRAGUE",
      "POSTING_DATE": "20211117",
      "MARKET": "CME",
      "TRADETYP": "SE",
      "MAX_DOC_QTY": "14256.230",
      "TRANSPORT_CODE": "AR",
      "DOCNR": "4700278453",
      "TRADETYPALLLINES": [
        "GR",
        "EXP",
        "SE"
      ],
      "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": [
        "BARGE",
        "ES",
        "AR"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the Jolt Spec I got to :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TRADE_HEADER": {
        "TRADEDETAIL": {
          "TRADEDETAILLINE": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[&1]",
              "@(2,SEGMENT)": "[&1].SEGMENTH",
              "@(2,TRADE_NUM)": "[&1].TRADE_NUM",
              "@(2,PACKAGE_GUID)": "[&1].PACKAGE_GUID",
              "@(0,TRADETYP)": "[#1].TRADETYP_ALL",
              "@(0,TRANSPORT_CODE)": "[#1].TRANSPORT_CODE_ALL"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "TRADERECORD"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The Result of this Spec :

```json
{
  "TRADERECORD" : [ {
    "DOC_QTY" : "19956.930",
    "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY" : "0.000",
    "REM_MAX_QTY_TE" : "0.000",
    "XMDOCNR" : "5025087976",
    "DOCITM" : "0000012001",
    "COMMODITY" : "RB",
    "TRADING_COMPANY" : "3862",
    "PERIODICITY" : "PRAGUE",
    "POSTING_DATE" : "20211117",
    "MARKET" : "CME",
    "TRADETYP" : "GR",
    "MAX_DOC_QTY" : "19956.930",
    "TRANSPORT_CODE" : "BARGE",
    "DOCNR" : "4700253115",
    "SEGMENTH" : "1",
    "TRADE_NUM" : "NA-152",
    "PACKAGE_GUID" : "ASDER3785$%SDF",
    "TRADETYP_ALL" : [ "GR", "EXP", "CR" ],
    "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALL" : [ "BARGE", "AR", "LCL" ]
  }, {
    "DOC_QTY" : "12256.230",
    "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY" : "0.000",
    "REM_MAX_QTY_TE" : "0.000",
    "XMDOCNR" : "5025092776",
    "DOCITM" : "0000014021",
    "COMMODITY" : "RB",
    "TRADING_COMPANY" : "3862",
    "PERIODICITY" : "PRAGUE",
    "POSTING_DATE" : "20211117",
    "MARKET" : "CME",
    "TRADETYP" : "EXP",
    "MAX_DOC_QTY" : "12256.230",
    "TRANSPORT_CODE" : "AR",
    "DOCNR" : "4700234521",
    "SEGMENTH" : "1",
    "TRADE_NUM" : "NA-152",
    "PACKAGE_GUID" : "ASDER3785$%SDF"
  }, {
    "DOC_QTY" : "14256.210",
    "ACT_NOM_CONSUMED_QTY" : "0.000",
    "REM_MAX_QTY_TE" : "0.000",
    "XMDOCNR" : "5025023562",
    "DOCITM" : "0000012041",
    "COMMODITY" : "RB",
    "TRADING_COMPANY" : "3862",
    "PERIODICITY" : "PRAGUE",
    "POSTING_DATE" : "20211117",
    "MARKET" : "CME",
    "TRADETYP" : "CR",
    "MAX_DOC_QTY" : "14256.230",
    "TRANSPORT_CODE" : "LCL",
    "DOCNR" : "4700278453",
    "SEGMENTH" : "1",
    "TRADE_NUM" : "NA-152",
    "PACKAGE_GUID" : "ASDER3785$%SDF"
  } ]
}
```

How do I get the "TRADETYP_ALL" And "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALL" repeated in All Detail records

And I also want to add another TAG "TRADETYP_CODE_ALL" combining the values of "TRADETYP_ALL" And "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALL"

"TRADETYP_CODE_ALL" : [ "GR-BARGE", "EXP-AR", "CR-LCL" ]

Any help in that direction Appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think _the condition_ and _the desired JSON value_ are not compatible, are they ?

Comment: Instead of checking the condition can we break the header/detail json into seperate detail jsons with 2 tags flattened with all the values in all the detail jsons

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Can you check the jolt spec what am I missing and how do I concat to string attributes

Answer (score 0):

So far so good, just would be suitable to add a **modify** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TRADE*": {
        "TRADE*": {
          "TRADE*": {
            "*": {
              "@": "a[&1].TRADERECORD",
              "@(2,TRADE_NUM)": "a[&1].TRADERECORD.TRADE_NUM",
              "@(2,PACKAGE_GUID)": "a[&1].TRADERECORD.PACKAGE_GUID",
              "@(0,TRADETYP)": "b[#1].TRADETYPALLLINES",
              "@(0,TRANSPORT_CODE)": "b[#1].TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "TRADER*": {
            "TRADETYPALLLINES": "@(4,b[0].TRADETYPALLLINES)",
            "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": "@(4,b[0].TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Edit : If you also need to add a new attribute

(*namely* : `"TRADETYP_TCODE_ALL" : [ "GR-BARGE", "EXP-AR", "CR-LCL" ]`)

composed of concatenated components of newly created arrays, then use the

following one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TRADE*": {
        "TRADE*": {
          "TRADE*": {
            "*": {
              "@": "a[&1].TRADERECORD",
              "@(2,TRADE_NUM)": "a[&1].TRADERECORD.TRADE_NUM",
              "@(2,PACKAGE_GUID)": "a[&1].TRADERECORD.PACKAGE_GUID",
              "@(0,TRADETYP)": "b[#1].TRADETYPALLLINES",
              "@(0,TRANSPORT_CODE)": "b[#1].TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "TRADER*": {
            "TRADETYPALLLINES": "@(4,b[0].TRADETYPALLLINES)",
            "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": "@(4,b[0].TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "b": {
        "*": {
          "TRADETYPALLLINES": { "*": "&3.&" },
          "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALLLINES": { "*": "&3.&" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "b": {
        "*": "=join('-',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "b": {
        "*": "TRADETYP_TCODE_ALL"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&",
          "@(2,TRADETYP_TCODE_ALL)": "&1.TRADERECORD.TRADETYP_TCODE_ALL"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you that works , but one last suggestion How to get combined collection of
"TRADETYP_ALL" And "TRANSPORT_CODE_ALL"

"TRADETYP_TCODE_ALL" : [ "GR-BARGE", "EXP-AR", "CR-LCL" ]

Comment: That is very elegant solution , I am trying to understand step-by-step each operation. Thank you great work !